# How to determine the best number of threads for I/O in an application

Tags: multithreading

I'm writing an application that will run on a Windows Server with 6 cores.

Big picture -- 10,000 users attempting to access the same files on a disk with read/write operations.

10,000 users are queued into a certain number of "Access Threads".  These access threads are queued into a single "Disk Access" thread.

Besides a WAG - how to determine what a "good" number (X) of "Access Thread" should be used?

I stated that the computer has 6 cores but I'm not sure that would impact the number since the whole application is 80% disk access and 20% data processing.

What are the potential trade-offs I should consider to implement 10,000 to one --- OR ---- 10,000 to X to one -- and if the later is true what should X be?

I'm using C++ as the language.

Thanks for any insight.

Several comments about overlapped IO I should clarify on.  The application is NOT centered on single disk access (as IO) but one acquiring data from multiple disk files - process that data (differently for each "Access Thread" and returning a "package" of resultant data.  I'm sorry I did not clarify this as the comments appear to be treating "Disk Access" as the main question.

In reality - the single disk access thread is an single entry point to an industrial database server - that is why I don't think overlapped IO is appropriate.

Comment: You should use Overlapped IO for this, not threads. Using threads for IO is a workaround for OSes that don't have real async IO.

Comment: As said above, you need to use asynchronous IO for the IO and a good threadpool for the CPU tasks.

Comment: I did not clarify that each of the "Access Threads" perform multiple Disk operations along with data processing from the acquired disk data - so I believe "overlapped IO" in not appropriate.

Comment: It is. you just need to design your code in a way that the processing happens with threads/threadpool, then when it's done you start an asynchronous IO operation. when this is done you again run a CPU task on a thread/threadpool and so one. maybe read a node.js tutorial to see how it's done in other technologies, for actual code examples.

Comment: Please see above that the "Disk Access" thread is a single point entry to a database server.

Comment: You have articulated your question as an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  You don't necessarily want the optimal number of threads, you want optimal performance.  You should let go of achieving that by just tuning the number of threads involved.

Comment: I agree but tuning suggest starting somewhere - hence a WAG.  Is there any logic to start at a certain number besides one?

Comment: Do you mean that for some unspecified reason, you can only "read" one "file" at a time, no parallelism allowed there? In that case, it depends on processing time versus IO time. If processing takes less time than IO, you need at most one processing thread and one IO thread. If processing takes longer than IO by a factor of N, you need N processing threads with N being no greater than the number of cores you have.

Comment: Thanks - I just need to instrument db response vs data processing time to determine X.